# filter JSON log events in CloudWatch with field dotted keys

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to filter logs in CloudWatch that field key has dot inside.

For example, suppose we have the following JSON

```
{
    "trace.traceid": "18552fad59836133",
    "trace.spanid": "6eca8ae25f08605a",
    "peer.address": "111.111.111.222:4444",
    "eventType": "UpdateTrail",
    "sourceIPAddress": "111.111.111.111"
}
```

and I want to use the selector `{$.peer.address="111.111.111.222:4444"}`
but the dot indicates field "address" inside object "peer" and not the flat key as described.

Answer (score 2):

The back tick is the magic character:

```
`peer.address`
```

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax could possibly work:

```
"\"peer.address\": \"111.111.111.222:4444\""
```

It will search for the exact string. Please note that in this syntax spacing matters.